# Java - classNotFound Exception from Windows command line but not Eclipse

Tags: java, command-line, javac

My code works fine in Eclipse, no build path errors or anything, however when I try to run my Java program from the command line, I get a `classNotFound Exception` on one of my inner classes. Not only do I not understand how I am getting this exception, but I am not even sure how to go about debugging it, since it looks and works fine in the IDE environment. Any help is appreciated!

**Edit**

I am writing a compiler for a subset of Java called J--, so I dont really want to get too into how it all works. But instead of calling `javac HelloWorld.java` I would call the equivalent `j-- HelloWorld.java`. `javac` works fine. You might say well the issue is with your code, but again it compiles and runs fine in Eclipse. So somewhere there seems to be a disconnect. Here is the Windows bash script if it helps:

```
set BASE_DIR=%~dp0
set j="%BASE_DIR%\..\"
set JAVA=java
set CPATH="%BASE_DIR%\..\lib\j--.jar;%BASE_DIR%\..\lib\spim.jar"
if "%CLASSPATH%" == "" goto runApp
set CPATH=%CPATH%;"%CLASSPATH%"

:runApp
%JAVA% -classpath %CPATH% jminusminus.Main "j--" %*

set JAVA=
set BASE_DIR=
set CPATH=
```

**Edit**

Thanks to Aubin, outputting the `.jar` file and comparing that with the `class not found` was how I was able to solve this conflict.

Comment: Can you show us some code? How are you compiling it on command line?

Comment: show what u try in command and folder structure

Comment: Eclipse takes care of your class locations, outside you need to specify `CLASSPATH` in your Java call.

Comment: I added some update. @PM77-1 can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: In Eclipse if you go into `"Run as" -> "Configuration"`, you will see that your current project is included in `CLASSPATH` by default.  Outside world does not know what your projects are.  Also, current directory is not in `CLASSPATH` unless you specify so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually Eclipse takes the sources from `src` and produces classes file into `bin`.

Try:

```
java -cp bin a.b.c.d.MyClass
```

To call your tool as `j-- <args>` you need to write a shell which embed the command:

```
java -cp bin a.b.c.d.MyClass $*
```

Comment: I added the script I am using. I dont see where that would be done ..?

Comment: Double check the content of your jar with `jar -tf j--.jar`

Comment: Ah, it appears you may be correct. There is `JSRAssign.java` in the jar, but the exception being thrown is looking for `JSrAssign.java`. Do you know how I can regenerate the jar?

Comment: if you have the classes file `*.class` you may recreate the jar with `jar -cf xxx.jar *.class`